# PowerShell ISE: Move duplicated files to another directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-5.1

I have to move older duplicated files into another directory while keeping the latest copy of each original filename. I need to keep them for a week in that location and then delete them. I have the delete-item already working just need some guidance on the moving the older duplicates.

Example

```
C:\Temp
text1.txt.           14:03 PM
text2.txt.           14:03 PM
txt1.csv             14:04 PM

C:Temp\Source
text1.txt.           14:01 PM
text2.txt.           14:04 PM
txt1.csv             14:06 PM
```

The goal is to have the written the older files into the D:\ for example while keeping the structure the same to avoid an overwritten error in the future with other files

```
D:\Temp
txt1.csv             14:04 PM
text2.txt.           14:03 PM

D:\Temp\SourceDropped
text1.txt.           14:01 PM
```

Result Outcome
and have the C:\ now like these for example

```
C:\Temp
text1.csv             14:03 PM

C:Temp\Source
text2.txt.           14:04 PM
txt1.csv             14:06 PM
```

I have tried this but the Move-Item is not moving them

```
 $dirC = 'C\Temp'
 $dirD = 'D:\Temp'

 Get-ChildItem -Path $dirC -Recurse -File |
 Select-Object -Property FullName, Name, LastWriteTime|
 Group-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
 Where-Object -Property Count -GT 1 |
 ForEach-Object {
 $_.Group |
 Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
 Select-Object -Skip 1 |
 Move-Item $_.FullName $dirD -Force #-WhatIf
 }
```

Also tried hashing them but it does not follow the structure when copied over

```
 $dirC = 'C\Temp'
 $dirD = 'D:\Temp'
 $hash = @{}
 Get-ChildItem -Path $dirC -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
 $filepath = $_.FullName
 $filehash = Get-FileHash -Path $filepath  -Algorithm SHA256 |
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash

 if($hash.ContainsKey($filehash)){
  Move-Item -Path $filepath -Destination $dirD -Force
 }
 }
```

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: what would be an alternative to this ? I got assign to only to use PowerShell ISE to find the duplicated files and move the older file names to a different directory temporary

Comment: The alternative to the ISE is mentioned in my previous comment (Visual Studio Code + its PowerShell extension), but that was just a general recommendation (hence the term _aside_), unrelated to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get going, essentially, first groups files by their `.Length` to avoid overhead of hashing them without need. Then, if the groups have more than 1 file, it will group them by MD5 hash and, only if the files have the same hash it will sort by `.LastWriteTime` and skip the newest one, the rest should be moved to `$dirD`.

`-WhatIf` should be removed once you have confirmed the code is doing what you need.

```bash
Get-ChildItem $dirC -File -Recurse | Group-Object Length | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -eq 1) {
        # nothing to do with a single file, no filehash needed
        return
    }

    # if the group has more than 1 file, get their hash
    $groupByHash = $_.Group | Group-Object { ($_ | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5).Hash }

    foreach ($group in $groupByHash) {
        if ($group.Count -eq 1) {
            # nothing to do with a single file, skip
            continue
        }

        # sort by LastWriteTime and skip the last file (the newest)
        $group.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
    }
} | Move-Item -Destination $dirD -WhatIf
```

Comment: This really only half worked if I had inside a function and called Move-Item D:\temp but only kept one file regardless of the other duplicated files.. I also did attempt robocopy and it got me to have the format saved into the D drive but it moved all files.. any other suggestions ?